# std::getline for an ifstream but using a char* instead of a string

Tags: c++, string, fstream, standards

I want to use the getline function with a `char*`.

I don't want to use `std::string` because I have a function that takes `char*` as parameters and writes to them and I don't want to write a whole new one just for strings.

Comment: And what has led you to this utterly ridiculous requirement?

Comment: Do you have a reason you don't want to include the string library? Knowing that will help us provide a solution you won't reject for the same reasons. Anyway, this sounds like you're asking for buffer overflows.

Comment: Also, all the information you need to do this can be found in the Standard Library reference that you're using. Voting to close as "reference"... or the next best thing. This is not a question.

Comment: No, you don't want to use char*.

Comment: Guys… such a straightforward question doesn't need much elaboration or justification. Why be so hard on this?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Because the question goes against good C++ habits. Without a good justification for such approach, the OP should be steered to the better solution.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: plus, who says the mysterious requirement that forbids string won't forbid a solution you present? When you put a strange requirement on a question, you should justify it, otherwise you could be wasting people's time.

Comment: Harsh, you won't lead Pilpel to the right way by closing down his question. No way to have a dialogue.

Comment: @john: While the question is closed, there's still a conversation going on here. You just added to it. Answers are definitely not the means to have a dialogue on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer for a simple question: use the stream's *member function* `getline` instead of the free function.

```
#include <fstream>
```

...

```
std::fstream my_stream;
char buffer[ 1000 ];

my_stream.getline( buffer, sizeof buffer );
```

Comment: Except that the member getline() functions are broken wrt/ detection of end of line when the line is exactly as long as the buffer. I strongly suggest against using those.

Comment: @wilx: I've never used the member functions, but the requirements in the Standard seem to match with the `string` functions. What's the subtle difference?

Comment: Is there any way to know when the eof has reached?

Comment: @Pilpel: Unless I'm missing something that wilx knows, it is the same as with `std::getline`. `my_stream.eof()` returns `true` after reading a line which does not terminate with a newline. `my_stream.fail()` returns true if that line was empty. In either case, evaluating `my_stream` as a Boolean yields `false`.

Comment: @Pipel: Hmm, I must admit I was not right. I clearly remember discussing this long time ago and the conclusion was it were broken. It is certainly harder to use than `std::getline()`. You still have to call `std::strlen()` on the buffer or (I am not sure if this is entirely correct) `stream.gcount() - !stream.eof()` to get the length of the line.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getline from istream

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
```

Comment: I have a function that takes char* as parameters and writes to them and I don't want to write a whole new one just for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough

```
char buffer[200];
cin.getline(buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

But there is no such thing as the string library, so your attempts not to include it are bound to be successful!

Comment: If you `#include <istream>` but do not `#include <string>`, in theory there is no free function `getline`, so OP does have in theory something of a point.

Comment: The standard seems to disagree with your last sentence, given that it has a whole chapter under the title "Strings library".