# Qt error iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer -fpermissive

Tags: c++, qt, casting, comparison, getline

I use Qt 4.5.1 and here in this console application when I want to receive user's input at ***if statement*** line it gets this error:

> iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer -fpermissive

here's my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   char ans;
   QDir mDir;
   QString mPath("A:/inetpub/wwwroot/xampp");
   if (mDir.exists(mPath))
      qDebug() << mDir.exists();

   else {
      qDebug() << "Do you wanna create the path? Y / N";
      // getline(cin, ans);
      cin >> ans;
      if (ans == "y") {
        qDebug() << "Now I create one";
        mDir.mkpath(mPath);
       }
   }

   return a.exec();
}
```

I have another trivial separated question as well; why I can't use **`getline(cin,string)`** function this way in Qt?

Comment: "I have another trivial separated question" - then post a second question. Only one question per question, please.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, You're right. I thought I could ask another small question inside exactly this code. Anyway, I'll not question two issues at the same time again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `string literal` with `char`

```
  if (ans == "y")
```

Should be

```
  if (ans == 'y')
```

Answering your second question.
`getline()` is  used to read a string or a line from input stream not single `char`.
and the syntax goes as below.

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

Comment: dear @kiran Biradar, you're just right. thanks, It solved. But would you please also answer why I can't use "getline" function that way in the code?

Comment: dear @kiran Biradar, you're right, it solved the problem completely. I wonder because I could use getline that way for char as well in VsStudio.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking [`ifstream::getline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119854/stdgetline-for-an-ifstream-but-using-a-char-instead-of-a-string)